# Creating a referral link to auto fill a user username on the registration form

Tags: php, html

How to create a referral link to auto fill a user username on the registration form? I don't have any idea on how does this work and even how to start it. All I have is:

```
https://mywebsite.com/register?ref=<?php echo ($user['username']);?>
```

Please, I need helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's superglobal `$_GET` to grab the query string from the URL, then add that to the input's value.

```php
$referral = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ref'] ?? '');
```

This will set the `$referral` variable to the given referral if it's there, otherwise, it'll be an empty string. Now you can use that in your input so set the referral.

```
<input type="text" name="referral" value="<?php echo $referral; ?>" />
```

Then when posted, you can check if a referral was set for this new registration and handle that accordingly. Whether that'll be setting a value in the database, sending the referral user an email, etc.

```php
if (isset($_POST['referral'])) {
    // Handle the referral.
}
```

Hope that give's you some ideas.

Comment: please this first line $referral = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ref'] ?? ''); where do i input it in my codes, am new to this please

Comment: Before you use the variable in the input, at the top of the file will work.